# How to get number of packets received, Average round trip time from ping command if I use popen

Tags: c++, linux, ping

I have to ping the given IP address and I need to print the below values in C++. It is fine to use popen and get the output.

```
1) Average Response Time
2) Data Block Size
3) Failure Count
4) Max. Response time
5) Min. Response time
6) Number Of Repetitions
7) Success Count
8) TimeOut
```

If I use popen, I will get a file pointer and I need to read on this file pointer to get the whole output and I have to extract the values using some string manipulation. Can any one please let me know if there is any other way instead of using string manipulation? Is there any data structure will be maintained by Operating System through which I can get the values after executing ping command?

Comment: No, `ping` is not an OS primitive, it is a functionality implemented by the application program `ping`. You can either use the program and parse its output, or reimplement all this functionality yourself. The latter should not be too hard as `ping`is open source, but you should be careful with the licensing.

Comment: "I don't want to do something a ridiculously easy way. Surely there must be some really hard way instead, right?"

Comment: @DavidSchwartz : I feel reading a data structure value is more easy than doing string manipulation. Do you feel different? Anyway now as it is clear there won't be any structure maintained, I have to do your easier way :)

Comment: @kadina Yeah, I do feel different. Maintaining a data structure in the kernel and creating and using APIs to access it is *way* more complex than just parsing some strings. If you don't believe me, try both approaches and see which one takes you longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a BETTER way than extracting the results from the string your read. Exactly the BEST way to parse the string, I'm not sure of [mostly because I haven't spent much time thinking about that!]

An alternative is of course to write your own internal implementation of `ping`, but I'm fairly sure that is a whole lot more work than using a parser on the `popen` on the system `ping` - unless you want VERY portable code [but that'd then also require a very portable networking package, since native networking is not very portable either].